# Bash: Find files with "find" in a folder tree that has trailing whitespace

Tags: bash, find

I have a super weird directory structure, that might have trailing whitespace in folder names such as:

```
"/path/to /file /with /folders /that /contain /whitespaces /file.ext"
```

I want the bash "find" function to pick those up while it traverses the file tree - the default recursive nature of it doesn't pick them up apparently.

I'd need a specific find command, that picks up *all* directory structures (e.g. not filtering only for those that have this "anomaly"), including those having trailing (white)spaces.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: `find` will "pick up" those folders just fine. Apparently you're having trouble *using* those pathnames after `find` reports them, but you haven't shown us what you're trying to do or how you're trying to do it or how the result differs from what you expected or wanted. Without that information, we can't help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and see if it offers any clues:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I D echo \"D\"
```

"-print0" and "xargs -0" should preserve your tricky directory names.